# Prevent a record from being deleted

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex

I am trying to prevent a record, which is a child of Object "A," from being deleted if the stage field of the object "A" has "Completed" as a value.

How can I use a trigger to meet the condition?
If trigger can't do it, is there a better way of doing this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What did you try? Can you give a [mcve] to better explain your issue ? See [ask]

Answer (score 0):

If the relation is master-detail you could do a rollup summary and validation rule on the master object, something like `ISPICKVAL(Stage__c, 'Completed') && PRIORVALUE(Rollup__c) > Rollup__c`.

If it's just a lookup - trigger on the child object. Validation rules don't fire on records being deleted.

Something like this (there may be syntax errors, but just to give you idea)

```
trigger ObjectATrigger on ObjectA__c (before delete){

    Map<Id, Parent__c> parents = new Map<Id, Parent__c>([SELECT Id
        FROM Parent__c 
        WHERE Stage__c = 'Completed' 
            AND Id IN (SELECT Parent__c FROM ObjectA__c WHERE Id IN :trigger.old)]);

    for(ObjectA__c o : trigger.old){
        if(parents.containsKey(o.Parent__c)){
            o.addError('Nice try');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for asking the question so ambiguously. I was actually curious about preventing insert/update/delete on the "File" object if it's related parent's status field value is set to 'completed.' The answer to this was to utilize triggers on ContentDocument and ContentDocumentLink. Thanks!